# List Interface (adding linkedlist to a list of lists)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

I just came across this code that works

```
List<List<Integer>> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedList<Integer> curList = new LinkedList<>();
parentList.add(curList);
```

I guess I was a bit thrown off because I didn't expect you'd be able to add a LinkedList to something declared as a List. I thought you would have had to do something like

```
List<Integer>curList = new LinkedList<>();
parentList.add(curList);
```

I thought the whole point of declaring / initializing a LinkedList or ArrayList as a List was so that you could add them to a List even though they are implemented as LinkedLists and ArrayLists.

edit: Or am I getting confused with the fact that we do this as an abstraction layer - we declare it as a List so that even if its made up of arraylists and linkedlists, we can still use the same List interface functions on all of them. And we can add linkedlists to a List of Lists because linkedlists are just implementing the List interface

Comment: Your 'edit' comment is correct. You use an interface precisely because you want to allow the use of any implementation of that interface. You don't care if the user gives you an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, you just want a `List`. One day you might want a `Database` and you don't care if it's `MySQL` or `Postgresql` as long as it implements all of the `Database` methods. In this way you can write code that doesn't care so much about specifics. Leave the code at the very edge to handle it, and internally you can operate more abstractly.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` extends `AbstractSequentialList` which in turns extends `AbstractList` and `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList`.
So both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` underlying extend the same subclass. The `add` method on a `List` interface has a restriction to add elements of similar type. Therefore both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are considered to be similar and therefore are allowed to be added.

Also logically adding the `LinkedList` doesn't changes the behavior of elements inside it as the order is maintained even after getting added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

This:

```java
LinkedList < Integer > curList = new LinkedList<>() ;  // <-- Declared as `LinkedList`.
parentList.add( curList ) ;
```

… and this:

```java
List < Integer > curList = new LinkedList<>() ;        // <-- Declared as `List`.
parentList.add( curList ) ;
```

… have the same effect.

In both cases, `parentList` is expecting to receive a `List` that holds `Integer` objects. A `LinkedList` is simultaneously both a `LinkedList` *and* a `List`. So passing `curList` defined as a `List` or defined as a `LinkedList` makes no difference. In both cases a `List` is received by the `parentList.add` method.

Assigning a `LinkedList` object to a `List` variable does not change the nature of the object.

## `List` means any kind of `List` implementation: `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, whatever

Your first collection, `parentList`, is a list of lists.

- Each element within that list is itself another list. The declaration `List< List < Integer > > parentList` tells us that we have a list of lists of `Integer` objects.
- Both the outer list and the inner lists can be any kind of `List`, not necessarily an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Your second collection, `curList`, is simply a list of `Integer` objects.

- We know this from its declaration, `LinkedList < Integer > curList`.
- In this declaration, we are saying the list is definitely a `LinkedList`, not any other kind of `List`.

Here is a full example.

First we make a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) object holding lists of `Integer` objects. This outer list is empty.

Then we add a list of three single-digit odd numbers (3, 5, 9). This non-modifiable list is generated by the [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) method. The concrete implementation of `List` used for the object returned by `List` in not promised, and may vary with the situation and the version of Java. All we know for sure is that we are getting *some* implementation of `List` that holds `Integer` objects.

Then we create a `LinkedList` holding `Integer` objects. After adding a couple of double-digit numbers, we add the list to the outer list.

Here are the key points to this code that seem to be confusing you:

- We could have declared this `curList` variable as the more general `List < Integer > curList` rather than the more specific `LinkedList < Integer > curList`. The type of `List` used for `curList` is irrelevant. The outer list `parentList` has said it does not care about which `List` implementation is added as an element, only that the added element be *some* kind of `List` that holds `Integer` objects.
- We could decide that the outer list would be better served if it were a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList`. If we so decide, we could simply change `List< List < Integer > > parentList = new ArrayList<>();` to `List< List < Integer > > parentList = new LinkedList<>();` — and none of the other code would break. We can switch `new ArrayList` to `new LinkedList` without changing any other code. That is the benefit of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) in [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

[image: diagram of a list of lists]

```java
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        List< List < Integer > > parentList = new ArrayList<>();
        parentList.add( List.of( 3 , 5 , 9 ) ) ;  // `List.of` returns *some* kind of (unmodifiable ) `List`; we do not know the concrete class nor do we care. 
        
        LinkedList < Integer > curList = new LinkedList<>();
        curList.add( 21 ) ;
        curList.add( 42 ) ;
        
        parentList.add(curList);
        System.out.println( parentList ) ;

    }
}
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mkyT94).

> [[3, 5, 9], [21, 42]]

In that output, we see a collection, a `List` that contains two elements. Each element is itself a `List`, a list of `Integer` element. The first element of the outer list holds a reference to a list of three `Integer` objects as elements, while the second element of the outer list holds a reference to a list of two `Integer` objects as elements.

You said:

> I guess I was a bit thrown off because I didn't expect you'd be able to add a LinkedList to something declared as a List.

That something (`parentList`) is declared as a list of lists. The `LinkedList` you are passing is a `List`, so it fits, it is a matching type. Any `LinkedList` is also a `List`.

If you wanted the outer list (`parentList`) to hold only `ArrayList` objects rather than any kind of `List`, you would have declared it as:

```java
List< ArrayList < Integer > > parentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

With such a declaration, passing `new LinkedList<>()` to its `add` method would have resulted in a compiler error. Square peg, round hole.

But you would only make a declaration if your code later has a need for methods that are exclusive to `ArrayList` class, that are not defined in the more general `List` interface. Generally, you should use the most general interface or superclass that meets your needs, rather than the more specific concrete class or sub-interface. If `List` has the methods your later code needs, then declare `List< List < Integer > > parentList`. This gives you flexibility.

You said:

> I thought you would have had to do something like
>
> `List<Integer>curList = new LinkedList<>();`
>
> `parentList.add(curList);`

When you assign a `LinkedList` object to a `List` variable, **you are not changing anything**. A `LinkedList` object is simultaneously both a `ListedList` *and* a `List`.

When you pass `curList` to the `parentList.add` method, all that method sees is a `List`. Whether you declare `curList` as a `List` or `LinkedList` does not matter to the `add` method. The compiler checks that whatever is being passed into `add` is (a) *some* kind of `List` implementation, *any* `List` implementation, and (b) holds `Integer` objects.